# memcpy() doesn't seem to work

Tags: c, memcpy

I'm having trouble with memcpy() and I don't have a clue on where I went wrong.

Code can be seen here: http://pastebin.com/tebksExR

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct tmp__ {
   unsigned int num;
   unsigned short id;
   unsigned short type;
} tmp_str;

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
   tmp_str hdr;
   char *str = NULL;

   str = calloc(18, sizeof(char));
   memset(&hdr, 0, sizeof(hdr));

   hdr.num = 0;
   hdr.id = 0;
   hdr.type = 21845;
   memcpy((void *) str, (void *) &hdr, sizeof(hdr));
   printf("STR: %s\n", str);

   free(str);
   return 0;
}
```

On executing it, all I see is just "STR". Nothing is seen on the memory region pointed by str too.

```
(gdb) b 23
Breakpoint 1 at 0x8048494: file memcpy.c, line 23.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/a.out 

Breakpoint 1, main (argc=1, argv=0xbffff234) at memcpy.c:23
23     memcpy((void *) str, (void *) &hdr, sizeof(hdr));
(gdb) n
24     printf("STR: %s\n", str);
(gdb) n
STR: 
26     free(str);
(gdb) info locals 
hdr = {num = 0, id = 0, type = 21845}
str = 0x804b008 ""
```

Where did I go wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

When you specify `%s`, `printf` expects a null-terminated string. It can't tell that you allocated 18 bytes and you want the contents of those bytes printed. It looks at `*str`, sees a null byte, and stops looking.

Comment: Yes, that's correct, but why the memory region pointed by str is empty (in the gdb trace)?

Comment: @F430: Because GDB is expecting a null-terminated string too.

Comment: @^: Then, how can I actually see the what's there in the memory? I guess I cannot use str as it is a char *

Comment: @F430: In gdb? I believe there's a command to print out the contents of a region of memory, where you get to specify the starting address and length. Use that. In your actual code? Use the `tmp_str`. Don't try to treat things as byte sequences unless that's really the most natural way to treat them.

Answer (score 2):

Your data *is* getting moved. If you declared:

```
tmp_str* str2 = (tmp_str*)str;
```

then it would display properly in the debugger. You're just looking at the data wrong-- your code is executing properly.

Answer (score 2):

As was pointed out, since the first byte of `str` is `'\0'`. a simple `printf("%s",str);` statement will do nothing (it will stop at the first byte which indicates "end of string").  Instead, you could try

```
int ii;
printf("STR in hex:\n");
for(ii = 0; ii < sizeof(hdr); ii++) {
  printf("%02x ", str[ii]);
}
printf("\n");
```

This will now print every byte in `str` as a hex number; you will see that the copy went OK.

If you would like, you could replace this with

```
int ii;
printf("STR in hex:\n");
for(ii = 0; ii < sizeof(hdr); ii++) {
  printf("%c", str[ii]);
}
printf("\n");
```

And you will see the actual characters (but some of them may be "unprintable" and might have unexpected side effects in your terminal).

Answer (score 1):

`str` is a string (`char *` terminated by `'\0'`) and `hdr` is a structure, which doesn't even have a string field.  If you want to convert `hdr` to a human-readable string, you'll have to use `printf` or `sprintf` with the proper conversion specifiers.

Comment: I just want data movement and actually not trying to make hdr, a string.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you set `hdr.num = 0;`, so the first byte of copied chunk of memory is equal to `0`, so the first character of your string is NULL, which marks it's ending, so nothing is printed.